# Can connect to website with one device but not another

Tags: networking, internet

I'm having trouble connecting to a particular website and server on a particular computer on a particular network. This is a problem for me as it is a website and server I visit very regularly. We've not long moved house and thus changed network setup, though I was having problems at my previous location as well.

I can't isolate it to my computer, because:

- a second computer (on Wi-Fi) can't access the services, but my phone on the same Wi-Fi network can
- when I switch the computer to my phone as a Wi-Fi hotspot, the services work perfectly (which also rules out a software and/or OS problem)

I can't isolate it to my network, because:

- I had a similar problem with a similar setup at my previous location
- I managed to "fix" it such that it worked last night using the same setup, but it's now no longer working. Trying the "fix" again gave no results

I can't isolate it to my browser - it fails in both Chrome and Firefox. Furthermore, there is a standalone client program for this website that also does not work.

The website is [www.multiplayerrobot.com](http://multiplayerrobot.com). [DFEOJM](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com) continually says the website is still up and it's my problem.

The setups - all of these fail except the last two.

- ```
  fibre box --- Wi-Fi modem/router --- powerline adapter --- my desktop
  ```
- ```
  fibre box --- Wi-Fi modem/router ))) my desktop
  ```

  (there is no way to get a single Ethernet cable from the router to my desktop)
- ```
  fibre box --- Wi-Fi modem/router ))) laptop
  ```
- ```
  fibre box --- Wi-Fi modem/router --- laptop
  ```
- ```
  fibre box --- Wi-Fi modem/router ))) my phone
  ```

  (the website works, but the phone does not and cannot utilise the client program mentioned above)
- ```
  my phone as a hotspot ))) my desktop
  ```

  (the only configuration that reliably works, but is cumbersome)

I'm well and truly out of ideas. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could it be an MTU issue?

Comment: Interestingly, I can't access www.multiplayerrobot.com from Western Australia (it just times out), but pinging works fine (the URL resolves to 98.124.199.1). `https://98.124.199.1/` also times out, but `http://98.124.199.1/` returns *"We're sorry, but we were unable to process the redirection request for the site you are attempting to access."* (using Firefox). I tried with a VDSL connection and a 4G mobile connection (both as a hotspot and directly).

Comment: @davidgo how can I diagnose/fix that? I've never dealt with MTU before

Comment: Try using Google. (I've answered thids question too many times before here)

Comment: @davidgo I do not appear to have an MTU problem.